# Duplicate BLE devices with different bluetooth addresses

Tags: android, macos, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an android application which scans for and lists all BLE devices in range. I am seeing that iMacs and Macbooks sometimes get picked up twice with different bluetooth hardware addresses.

For example, in the list will be:

- Peter's iMac (45:45:45:45)
- Peter's iMac (55:55:55:55)

In code I can see it detecting both devices separately, and also confirmed that it is not just my app that is the issue as the same happens in the OS's bluetooth scan for devices.

Can anyone please shed some light as to why iMacs and Macbooks will broadcast two ble signals with two different addresses.

PS. It is happening on many iMacs and Macbooks in the office, so it is not just one faulty iMac that is the issue.

Comment: Do the addresses change over time? If you aren't paired with an iOS or Mac OS device then you should see different, random addresses periodically as Apple does this to prevent passive tracking

Comment: So in one list of search results the same device appears twice with a different address in each. Today it looks like the one address stayed the same, but the other has changed. Maybe I will rule this as apple weird behavior.